# I installed the Ubuntu-14.04 in the VirtualBox on my Mac, but I don't know how to connect it

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I installed the Ubuntu-14.04 in the VirtualBox on my Mac.

[image]

You see I use `ip a`, there shows only two network-interface(`127.0.0.1/8` and `10.0.2.15/24`).

In my Mac, I use `ifconfig`:

```
$ ifconfig
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=1203<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TXSTATUS,SW_TIMESTAMP>
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether a0:99:9b:17:50:07 
    inet6 fe80::10f4:b82a:315f:2a5%en0 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x4 
    inet 192.168.1.3 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
en1: flags=963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 4a:00:02:2c:3b:30 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en2: flags=963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 4a:00:02:2c:3b:31 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
p2p0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
    ether 02:99:9b:17:50:07 
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 4a:00:02:2c:3b:30 
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x2
    member: en1 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 5 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en2 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 6 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: <unknown type>
    status: inactive
awdl0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1484
    ether 0e:1a:b1:4d:a5:a8 
    inet6 fe80::c1a:b1ff:fe4d:a5a8%awdl0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x9 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
utun0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 2000
    inet6 fe80::e687:4e43:6318:90df%utun0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xa 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
```

I can not in my Mac Terminal to ping `10.0.2.15`, so I can not use the Mac Terminal to connect the VM, is there a solution to access it? I just mean, like in Windows use Xshell to ssh connect the VM.

Answer (score 0):

By default, VirtualBox uses NAT networking. You will not be able to reach the VM from your host's networking. To do so, you need to modify the VM's network adapter settings to be bridged or host-only.

Bridged will bridge the VM's network adapter, allowing it to obtain DHCP and such from the network the host is on. You will be able to reach it from the host, as well as other devices on your network. The VM will also have internet access, assuming that your local network does.

Host-only, as the name suggests, creates a network that only exists between the VM(s) and your host. You will be able to connect to the VM, but the VM will not have internet access.

After changing the adapter settings, you will likely need to restart the VM's network interface(s) in order to obtain the correct DHCP configuration, if applicable.